# Match limited amount of spaces, ignoring those that are part of a tag

Tags: php, regex, xml, pcre

I'm trying to create a regex that matches the five last "words" of the input, where a "word" is defined as anything that matches `[^ ]+` or `[^ ]*<[^>]*>[^ ]*` (so anything separated by spaces, but counting spaces between `<` and `>` as letters)

I tried this:

```
/([^ ]+(?:(?<!<[^>]+) +(?![^<]*>)(?:.*?)){0,4})$/
```

but it gives me the error that lookbehind must be fixed lenght.

Say I have the following string:

```
'It\'s just that he <span class="verb">appear</span>ed rather late.'
```

it should match

```
'that he <span class="verb">appear</span>ed rather late.'
```

Comment: Please add one or more example strings and the expected output.

Comment: One way would be

    `while (preg_match('/<[^> ]* /',$input)) $input = preg_replace('/(<[^> ]*) /','$1'."\0",$input);`
    `preg_match('/(?:(?:[^ ]+) ){0,4}[^ ]*$/',$input,$match);`
    `$input = str_replace("\0"," ");`
    `$match[0] = str_replace("\0"," ");`
but that seems rather crude and might break things if the used character (\0 here) appears in the input already

Comment: in case if you weren't aware - please take a look at the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags :-)

Comment: Is pure regex needed here for some reason?
Isn't it much easier to first use `strip_tags()` function and then conut "words" or even `explode()` string ?

Comment: Decent idea, SilentDariusz, but the tags need to stay.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution was already pretty close. Please see this one:

```
$str = 'It\'s just that he <span class="verb">appear</span>ed rather late.';
$reg = '/(([^ ]*<[^>]*>[^ ]*)+|[^ ]+)/'; // let me know if you need explanation
if (preg_match_all($reg, $str, $m)) { // "_all" to match more than one
    $m = array_slice($m[0], -5, 5, true); // last 5 words
    //$m = implode(' ', $m); // uncomment this if you want a string instead of array
    print_r($m);
}
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [2] => that
    [3] => he
    [4] => <span class="verb">appear</span>ed
    [5] => rather
    [6] => late.
)
```

Comment: Nice. Works for my specific case.

Probably won't work if there were any nested tags (say, if there was something like `<em><span class="verb">appear</span>ed</em>`), but luckily that isn't the case for me.

Comment: Right. In fact there can be more issues. Remember: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

```
preg_match('~^(?:\s*[^>\s]*(?:>[^<]*<[^>\s]*)*){0,5}~', strrev(rtrim($str)), $m);
$result = strrev($m[0]);
```

Comment: this returns `span class="verb">appeared rather late.`